# How to execute python script using spark submit in php?

Tags: php, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I am working on an PHP application using MongoDB as a database platform. Collection in MongoDB has massive volume of data .Hence I have opted for Apache Spark to generate analytics.

I need to execute spark-submit command from PHP application.But its execution doesn't return any output to PHP application.

Following is code snippet

```
$result=shell_exec('./bin/spark-submit examples/src/main/python/pi.py'); 
print_r($result);
```

Please suggest me an appropriate solution

Answer (score 0):

Besides ensuring the Python script is outputting data, if you bang your head against the wall for too long you could consider using the Python script to put data into a database or file to be pulled from by PHP.

Comment: Thanks for answering to my question.But I need a proper method to invoke spark application from php application